# How to run npm lib in lambda

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-opensearch

I want to use the elactic dump tool to send my index to S3.

I have found this plugin: https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump

I know that i have to create a Zip with the npm lib. But once it is done, i don't know how to call this kind of example insitde the my Nodejs lambda:

```
elasticdump \
  --s3AccessKeyId "${access_key_id}" \
  --s3SecretAccessKey "${access_key_secret}" \
  --input=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --output "s3://${bucket_name}/${file_name}.json"
```

The last command is a shell command. How to call it with nodejs approach inside my lambda ?

Thanks a lot